# Python SQL table updated checker

Tags: sql, python-2.7, oracle-sqldeveloper, cx-oracle

I'm using Python 2.7 with a Oracle Database to run various scripts at different times. I'm using CX_Oracle in my python code but have come across a small problem. If the table on SQL has not refreshed overnight with the freshest data then my script will run at 7am whether the data has been updated or not.

Is there a way to check to see if tables have been updated in python? I know I can see if the SQL table by using the SQL statement

```
 SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(MAX(ora_rowscn)) from export01;
```

Does anyone know of a way I could incorporate some kind of check into my python script?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of database change notification which will notify your script whenever rows are inserted, updated, deleted, etc. There is a sample in the cx_Oracle package called "DatabaseChangeNotification.py" which will give you an idea of how the feature works.